# SQL Server : the function 'abs' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause

Tags: sql-server, sum

I am getting an error on line 10 in the SQL Server code shown below saying

> The function 'abs' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause

What I want to do is take the absolute value of each value in the column `MTM_DIFF_GBP` and get the total sum for each counterparty (cp).

```
select A.*, 
       dense_rank () over (order by A.ABS_MTM_DIFF_GBP desc)
from
    (
    select T.MTM_DATE, 
        case
            when T.TraderFullName is null then T.Department_Head
            else T.TraderFullName
        end as TraderFullName, T.CP, T.BOOK, T.PRODUCT_CLASS_ORIG, T.MTM_CURR, T.MTM_DIFF, T.MTM_DIFF_GBP, 
            sum(abs(T.MTM_DIFF_GBP) over (partition by T.CP)) as ABS_MTM_DIFF_GBP
    from 
        (
        select c.MTM_DATE, c.MTMCOBID, b.CurrentPrimaryTraderCode, p.TraderFullName, l.Department_Head, c.LatestBookKey, c.CP, c.BOOK, c.PRODUCT_CLASS_ORIG, c.MTM_CURR, ex.ExchangeRate, round(sum(MTM_VALUE_DIFF),2) as MTM_DIFF, round(ex.ExchangeRate * sum(MTM_VALUE_DIFF),2) as MTM_DIFF_GBP
        from ops.ClientValuationDiffs c
        left join Global.Book b
        on c.LatestBookKey = b.BookKey
        left join Global.TraderPhysical p
        on b.CurrentPrimaryTraderCode = p.TraderCode and b.EntityCode = p.EntityCode
        left join Global.LocalDepartmentRoles l
        on b.EntityCode = l.Entity and b.DepartmentCode = l.Department
        inner join Global.ExchangeRate ex
        on c.COBID = ex.COBId and ex.FromCurrencyCode = c.MTM_CURR
        where c.MTMCOBID = '20200727'
        and c.CP NOT IN ('BTMU','MUMSS','DEUTSCHE-TELEKOM','DEXIACLSA','EKS','HSHNORD','IBRD','INGBANK','KBN','NATIONALGRIDGAS','NORDLB')
        and c.AGREEMENT_TYPE  IN  ('CCP', 'ISDA')
        and c.CP != 'MUSI' 
        and c.PRODUCT_CLASS_ORIG !='COMS'
        and ex.ToCurrencyCode = 'GBP'
        and ex.RegionDataSetKey = '1'
        group by  c.MTM_DATE, c.MTMCOBID, b.CurrentPrimaryTraderCode, p.TraderFullName, l.Department_Head, c.LatestBookKey, c.CP, c.BOOK, c.PRODUCT_CLASS_ORIG, c.MTM_CURR, ex.ExchangeRate
        ) T
    ) A
```

Answer (score 3):

Your parens are in the wrong place.  You want `abs()` as an argument to `sum()`:

```
sum(abs(T.MTM_DIFF_GBP)) over (partition by T.CP)
```